# `jqgrid` is not a function error when working in mvc4 cshtml page but working fine in aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i am trying to bind json format data to jqgrid when i am trying the same code in aspx page its not throwing any error but in cshtml page page its throwing error that jqgrid is not a function.i cannt able to see the design of grid.My code is like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gridimgpath = 'themes/basic/images';
    $("#projectList").jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        height: 150,
        colNames: ['WorkSpaceName', 'Id'],
        colModel: [
    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 600 },
    { name: 'WorkSpaceName', index: 'WorkSpaceName', width: 600 },

    ],
        imgpath: gridimgpath,
        multiselect: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        hidegrid: false,
        caption: "WorkSpace Name",
        pager: '#gridpager',
        rowNum: 10,
        viewrecords: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40]
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'OauthVerifierNew',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {},
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert("hello")
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#projectList").setGridParam({ data: response }).trigger("reloadGrid");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);


        }
    });
    $("#projectList").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });

});
```

Comment: i  replaced the script folder after that its working f9

Comment: did you put the jqgrid dependency already on the aspx page?

Answer (score -1):

error like

> jqgrid is not a function

you are not adding jqgrid.js or jQGrid file on you page,

check "source" of your pages, both in cshtml and aspx page

and check on browser too, if jQgrid is really added or not.

Comment: someone does not understand question and answer lol.. he fixed with "i replaced the script folder after that its working f9" means what????? jqgrid was not added perfectly.. lol on down voter...